# Porting Arduino serial communication to standalone atmega328

Tags: arduino, usb, serial-communication, atmega

I have a fairly complex project done on Arduino2560, which I want to port to a standalone Atmega328. My problem is that one feature in the project is that it can communicate with my computer via serial (I made a C# program to handle it on the computer side, using the COM3 port). However, Arduino uses the USB communication for a virtual serial port, and I got a bit confused about how it could be done for the Atmega. It has the RX-TX lines, but what's next? Maybe use some serial-USB converters? What's the best approach for this? Is there anything I should be careful about?
Thanks.

Comment: What the question about? Use any USB-UART convertors (CP1202, FT232, CH340 etc.). the same as it done at the Arduino board.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didn't know what the board was using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you mention a specific port `COM3` on your computer I guess we can assume you have a native RS-232 port (one of those with the sub-D9 male connector that we were used to in the old days but are not so common anymore).

If that's the case, then you can get an [RS232 level shifter](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/449). You'll just have to make the connections to  RX, TX, Vcc, and GND and this device will change the [RS-232 voltage levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Voltage_level) to whatever your board requires (most likely 5V or 3.3V). Some (maybe most) high-end development boards include this kind of level shifter so maybe check yours in case you already have it (if you do you'll probably see a [MAX232 IC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAX232) somewhere). Or if you are crafty you can also [DIY](https://www.instructables.com/id/RS232-to-TTL-UART-Converter/).

If you prefer to connect to a USB port (then, of course, it won't be `COM3`unless you explicitly change the configuration on Windows Device Manager) you can go for a USB-to-serial adaptor. On that front, you have many choices, starting from the cheapest at maybe 5$, but I'd rather choose one based on the FTDI chip, which is nowadays quite ubiquitous and has proven its reliability. [This one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12731) is a good example, and at the same cost as the level shifter.

Now, are there any differences between using the native RS-232 or the USB adaptor? The answer is, for most practical purposes, no. If you go to the fine details, like buffer sizes, there will be differences, but if you need to go there you'll need to study the details in both cases to see if the port you have (or the one you're planning to add) meet your needs. For most scenarios, I would choose the USB, if only because you have it everywhere (most laptops don't have a native RS-232).

All of the above (based on RS-232 and/or USB) will work fine for cables running up to 5 meters (~15 ft.) for USB or maybe 10 to 15 meters (~30-45 ft.). This should be enough for most hobbyist or at-home projects. If you want to run longer cables you'll have to go for something like [RS-485](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485).

If you choose now the USB adaptor and you think you might need to relocate your board in the future to end up more than 20 meters (15 of RS-232 + 5 of USB) away from your computer just make sure your adaptor includes a TX Enable signal (TXEN). Most adaptors based on the FTDI chip will have this signal on a pin (like the one I linked above), and that will make your life way easier if you want to use RS-485 on a two-cable half-duplex bus.

**EDIT:** based on the feedback below there is new info that deserves a quick update.

First, you don't have an old school RS-232 port on your PC and second you have to design the connection on the microcontroller's side.

With that in mind it's clear you have to go for the USB solution. But you need to choose if you shift both sides to RS-232 levels or you stay at TTL. That decision depends again on the length of your bus. If it'll be really short (up to 2 meters) then you can stay on TTL, otherwise better shift to RS-232 to be on the safe side. There are many people who will tell you they have much longer serial links but how reliable they are you'll never know.

Since you have to design the board, I guess it makes sense to integrate the MAX232 and a sub D-9 connector there and get the [cable](https://www.soselectronic.hu/products/ftdi/us232r-100-blk-71853) you mentioned for your PC.

Or, you can add only a connector on the board and get the Sparkfun level shifter I linked above for the micro's side plus the same USB to RS-232 for your PC.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared it up a lot! I didn't mention that COM3 is the virtual port used by Arduino, so it's not a physical connector, I would use USB. I don't need more than 5m cable length, so I'll stick with RS232. However, I will need a comfortably breakable connection, so my idea is this: connect the RX, TX and GND to a 9 pin D sub connector based on [link](https://www.codrey.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/ESP8266-interfacing-with-UART.png). Then get this cable with built in MAX232 and FT232RL [link](https://www.soselectronic.hu/products/ftdi/us232r-100-blk-71853). Am I right?

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't have the native RS232 with the sub-D 9 in your computer you don't need the connector or the MAX232. Your microcontroller takes TTL levels so you can just go with something like the Sparkfun USB I linkes. If you buy the USB to RS232 you'll need the other one I linked (the RS232 level shifter) for the other side. That's an option too but unless you want to have the RS232 for other purposes... And these days almost everything is TTL anyway so I'm not sure it's worth the investment

Comment: You should be able to find something with a connector in just one piece, do you have a connector on the ATMega's side for the RX-TX signals? Something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/DIYmall-Adapter-Chipset-Arduino-ESP8266/dp/B014GZTCC6/ref=mp_s_a_1_4?keywords=usb+ttl+ftdi&qid=1561062327&s=gateway&sr=8-4) might be convenient but the pin connector is not particularly robust

Comment: I saw this cable at a local webshop, but I would prefer a more robust connector, that's why I thought about the D sub. I don't have a connector on the Atmega side yet, I'm designing the board right now.

Comment: I've added a couple of thoughts above. Take a look and let me know.

Comment: I think I'll go with the MAX232 - D-sub solution, it cheaper than the Sparkfun boards. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, have fun with your project!